# How do I vertically align text in a colorbox?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, vertical-alignment

How do I vertically align text that is inside of the cboxTitle-div (e.g. close-Box(text))? I use [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) for making modal popups.

The div-structure is this:

```
<div id="cBoxContent">
    <div id="cBoxTitle"></div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#cboxContent{overflow:hidden; background: #121219;
}
#cboxTitle{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; text-align:left; width:100%; color:#999; height: 38px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vertically center text by setting its `line-height` property to the height of the element it's sitting in.

```
#cboxTitle{
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    text-align:left; width:100%; 
    color:#999; 
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 38px;
}
```

This trick will only work if you know the height of your `div`, of course. [There are](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html) [other](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) [methods](http://web.archive.org/web/20091017204329/http://www.zann-marketing.com/developer/20050518/vertically-centering-text-using-css.html), but they're more complex.

Another method that isn't linked is to set the `div` containing your text to `position: relative;`, then setting `top` to 50% minus the one half the height of the element. This is best done in Javascript.